# Problema com Iframe no android

Tags: android, html5, ionic, vídeo

Estou querendo uma ajuda ...Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que está usando um iframe pra rola vídeo no app ...O problema é o seguinte: Quando eu testo no AppPreview do Intel Xdk o vídeo apresenta de boa mas quando eu gero o APK testo no telefone não apresenta nada fica branco... Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema ? Estou usando o INTEL XDK pra fazer o Build .

Comment: olha o código tenta incrementar mais caminhos para a execução do vide o ou função deve existir outras forma e caminhos que executem de maneira diferente

Comment: o problema desses atalhos de programação para evitar a dureza da "linguagem nativa" são tamanhos que no fim é trocar 6 por meia-duzia, pois o tempo que voce ganha para implementar a UI é inversamente proporcional ao tempo gasto em manutenção e na "desmistificação" do código gerado pelo framework!